# how to set a random key once using saltstack

Tags: salt-stack

I install a configuration for rails that looks like this (simplified):

```
production:
    secret_key_base: 800afb35d5086b2c60ebd35c01b2bd2b522c2492
    db_username: ...
    db_password: ...
```

and so it gets installed from a template file

```
{{ role }}:
    secret_key_base: {{ secret_key }}
    db_username: {{ db_user }}
    db_password: {{ db_pass }}
```

And the role and db user/pass get pulled from pillar and installed in that file.  The secret_key it would make sense to generate randomly, e.g., `{{ salt['random.get_str'](length=80) }}`.  But I want to generate it once, not every time the template is rendered.  (Changing the secret key invalidates cookies, not something to do on each salt run.)

The only solution I've found is two-phase:  I have a `template.in` file

```
{{ role }}:
    secret_key_base: ||secret_key_base||
    db_username: {{ db_user }}
    db_password: {{ db_pass }}
```

that I sed into my template file on any given minion:

```
/srv/salt/rails/secrets.yml:
  cmd.run:
    # Fill in the secret key base (used for cookies).  We can't use
    # jinja2 for this, since jinja would complain about the other
    # variables that it doesn't know how to replace.  We want our
    # output to be a jinja template.
    - name: |
        cat /srv/salt/rails/secrets.yml.in | \
          sed -e 's/||secret_key_base||/{{ salt['random.get_str'](length=80) }}/;' | \
          cat > /srv/salt/rails/secrets.yml
        chmod 400 /srv/salt/rails/secrets.yml
    - creates: /srv/salt/rails/secrets.yml
    - runas: root

/var/railroad/{{host_role}}/shared/config/secrets.yml:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://rails/secrets.yml
    - mode: 400
    - user: railroad-{{host_role}}
    - group: railroad-{{host_role}}
    - template: jinja
    - defaults:
        role: host_role
        db_username: m_u
        db_password: m_p
```

This works but has the disadvantage that a change to `secrets.yml.in` would not be propagated on to `secrets.yml`.  (Suppose we add another key to the secrets file.)  It also feels clunkier than necessary.

Is there a better way?

### A better way

As noted in the comments, a better way is to just generate the secret by hand (after all, it's only done at host setup) and store it in pillar, where we anyway have to say a few things about each host.

Here is what the working code eventually looked like, unsimplified for those who might want to see something more complex.  Much of the complexity is my `host_credentials` pillar data, which tries to characterise all that we need to know about each host.

```
{% set fqdn = grains.get('fqdn', 'unknown-host-fqdn') %}
{% set host_role = pillar['host_credentials']
                         [grains.get('fqdn')]
                         ['role'] %}
{% set examplecom_web_app = pillar['host_credentials']
                                  [grains.get('fqdn')]
                                  ['examplecom-web-app'] %}
{% set mysql_server_host = examplecom_web_app.mysql.host %}
{% set mysql_server_database = examplecom_web_app.mysql.database %}
{% set mysql_server_role = examplecom_web_app.mysql.role %}
{% set mysql_server_spec = pillar['host_credentials']
                                 [mysql_server_host]
                                 ['mysql'] %}
{% set mongodb_server_host = examplecom_web_app.mongodb.host %}
{% set mongodb_server_spec = pillar['host_credentials']
                                   [mongodb_server_host]
                                   ['mongodb'] %}
/var/examplecom/railroad/{{host_role}}/shared/config/secrets.yml:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://rails/secrets.yml
    - mode: 400
    - user: railroad-{{host_role}}
    - group: railroad-{{host_role}}
    - template: jinja
    - defaults:
        role: {{ host_role }}
        secret_key_base: {{ examplecom_web_app.secret_key_base }}
        mysql_hostname: {{ mysql_server_host }}
        mysql_username: {{ mysql_server_spec[mysql_server_database]
                                            [mysql_server_role]
                                            ['username'] }}
        mysql_password: {{ mysql_server_spec[mysql_server_database]
                                            [mysql_server_role]
                                            ['password'] }}
        mongodb_hostname: {{ mongodb_server_host }}
        mongodb_username: {{ mongodb_server_spec.username }}
        mongodb_password: {{ mongodb_server_spec.password }}
```

As an aside, I was happy to discover that jinja2 is white-space agnostic, which helps enormously with readability on such lookups.

Comment: Are you using the pillar system? I would simply put the secret in a pillar and generate it once manually on the master.

Comment: I am using pillar.  And, ... yes, that would be simpler.  Good idea.  Thanks.

Comment: @code_onkel For history (and to avoid people coming by trying yet more answers), would you like to note your answer as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend putting the secret in a pillar and generate the value once (manually) on the master. That way you can avoid doing the stateful on-the-fly-magic in your SLS file.

jma updated his question to include an example solution.

Comment: Thanks!  I've updated the original question with a final section, "a better way", that shows how this works out in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly:
 - this is salt-masterless run?
 - you generate some template file on masterless node (to have some static parts generated once)
 - you apply `file.managed` state to previously generated file?

Assuming my understandings:

First of all it **will** be propagated to another states if you set proper [`watch/require` statements](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html) but in your case this would be harder to achieve as you've used `cmd.run` for template parsing (you must add `stateful` argument [to express that there is some potential state changes underlying](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#stateful-argument))

Remarks:
 -  did you see [`file.blockreplace`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.blockreplace)? it seems that you can use this to replace first `cmd.run` and get file change detection "for free"
 - as for one time password generation, there is nice trick to do this simply by using [`grains.get_or_set_hash`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.grains.html#salt.modules.grains.get_or_set_hash)

As the generated password is not changing for given minion (you master-less node in your case) the `file.blockreplace` won't report any changes unless you add changes to the template

Having said this, I think we can go further and your state actually can be as simple as this (template changes will be propagated always, key will be generated once):

```
/var/railroad/{{host_role}}/shared/config/secrets.yml:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://rails/secrets.yml
    - mode: 400
    - user: railroad-{{host_role}}
    - group: railroad-{{host_role}}
    - template: jinja
    - defaults:
        role: host_role
        db_username: m_u
        db_password: {{ salt['grains.get_or_set_hash']('some:place:secret_key_base') }}
```

Comment: Yes, I think this would work.  But see @code_onkel's comment, above.  This is even easier just to stash in pillar and be done.

Comment: It is worth to mention here, that grains are not a good place to store secrets. I only found [this resource](https://www.reddit.com/r/saltstack/comments/7dcp4v/what_is_the_best_practice_to_generate_passwords/) that writes about it, but there are several reasons not to do so. The pillar is meant to store secrets.

Comment: Actually the external encrypted pillar or gpg_pillar is meant to store secrets - not just pillar. But author didn't say a word about such requirement